# ¿Cómo puedo activar un botón hasta que le toque turno?

Tags: html5, php7

Hola chicos estoy realizando un juego, en el que el primer jugador lance los dados, hasta que le toque el segundo jugador este estará desactivado, pero no se como representarlo en php. ¿Alguna idea? gracias de antemano.
[image: Foto de turnos]

```
<h1>Simulación de turnos</h1>
<form method="POST" action=""> 
    <label for="jugador1">Jugador 1</label>
    <input type="text" name="jugador1" value="<?php echo $dado1;?>">
    <input type="submit" name="btn1" value="DADO 1  <?php (!$jugadoractual)?'':'disabled'?>">
    <br>
    <br>
    <label for="jugador2">Jugador 2</label>
    <input type="text" name="jugador2" value=" <?php echo $dado2;?>">
    
    <input type="submit" name="btn2" value="DADO 2  <?php (!$jugadoractual)?'':'disabled'?>">
</form> 


<?php 
$dado1 = '';
$dado2 = '';
$jugadoractual = false;

if(isset($_POST['btn1']) && !isset($_POST['btn2'])){
    $jugador1 = $_POST['jugador1'];
    $jugadoractual = false;
    $dado1 = rand(1,6);
}else{
    if(isset($_POST['btn2'])){
        $jugador2 = $_POST['jugador2'];
        $jugadoractual = false;
        $dado2 = rand(1,6);
    }
}
```

?>

Comment: Lo que se me ocurre es que el `btn2` este desactivado al principio y luego cuando se presione el `btn1`, que se active

Comment: Puedes poner `Dado2` en estado `disabled` de entrada y cuando se haga click en `Dado1` al mismo tiempo activar `Dado2`, eso tendrías que hacerlo en el cliente (Javascript), no en el servidor (PHP), porque sería una acción posterior que dependerá del cliente.

Comment: ¿Con php solo no se podría hacer?